# Proving intuitive statements about THE in Isabelle

Tags: unique, isabelle

I would like to prove something like this lemma in Isabelle

```
lemma assumes "y = (THE x. P x)" shows "P (THE x. P x)"
```

I imagine that the assumption implies that `THE x. P x` exists and is well-defined. So this lemma ought to be true too

```
lemma assumes "y = (THE x. P x)" shows "∃! x. P x"
```

I'm not sure how to prove this because I've looked through all the theorems that turn up when I type "name: the" into the query box in Isabelle and they don't seem useful. I can't find the definition of `THE` either and I am not sure how to define it although I have an intuitive idea of what it means. I tried something like this although I am sure this is wrong

```
"(∃!x. P x) ⟹ THE x. P x = (SOME x. P x)"
```

and maybe even useless because I don't know how to define `SOME` either!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the assumption does *not* imply that `THE x. P x` ‘exists’, at least not in a sense that you would find satisfying. As HOL is a total logic, there is no notion of ‘well-definedness’ in the logic.

If you write `THE x. P x` when there is no unique `x` that satisfies `P`, then `THE x. P x` *is* still a value that ‘exists’ in HOL, but one that you cannot prove anything meaningful about (much like the `undefined` constant) and certainly not one for which `P` holds. The same is true for `SOME`, which is basically the same as `THE` with the difference that for `THE`, there has to be a *unique* witness for the property and for `SOME` uniqueness is not required.

The typical approach for showing something about `SOME x. P x` is that you first show that a witness exists (i.e. `∃x. P x`) and then you plug that into a rule like `someI_ex` which then tells you that `P (SOME x. P x)` indeed holds.

It's the same for `THE`, except that there you have to show that there is exactly *one* witness – which is what the `∃!` means (cf. the theorem `Ex1_def`). Showing this unique existence can be done e.g. with the rules `ex_ex1I` or `ex1I`. Then you can plug that fact into `theI'` and `the1_equality` to get the results you want.

By the way, the constant for `SOME` is called `Eps` (as in ‘Hilbert's ε operator’) and the others are `The` and `Ex1`. If you type e.g. `term Eps`, you can ctrl-click on the `Eps` and it takes you to its definition (or, in case of `Eps` and `The` rather their axiomatisations).

There's also a `LEAST` combinator for natural numbers that is very similar to `SOME` and can be quite useful sometimes (it's called ‘Least’ and the lemmas are `LeastI_ex` and `Least_le`).

Another side note: This idea that just because you can write down a term, it is not necessarily ‘well-defined’ in an intuitive sense is very common in Isabelle: you can divide by zero, you can write down the derivative of a non-differentiable function, the measure of a non-measurable set, the integral of a non-integrable function etc. You then get some kind of dummy value (e.g. 0 for division by zero or something completely absurd like `THE x. False`), but most of the theorems that talk about actual properties of derivatives, integrals, etc. do explicitly require that the thing is actually well-defined.