# How do I convert a predicate to a function in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle HOL, I have a predicate on two numbers like this:

```
definition f :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool"
  where 
    ...
```

I can prove that this predicate is morally a function:

```
lemma f_function:
  fixes x :: nat
  shows "∃! y . f x y""
  ...
```

Intuitively, this should be enough for me to construct a function `f' :: nat ⇒ nat` that is provably equivalent to `f'`, i.e.:

```
lemma f'_correct:
  "f x y = (f' x = y)"
```

But how do I do that?

```
definition f' :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  where
    "f' x ≡ ?"
```

What do I put in for the question mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach is to use the definite description operator `THE`:

```
definition f' :: "nat ⇒ nat" where "f' x = (THE y. f x y)"
```

If you have already proven that this `y` is unique, you can then use e.g. the theorem `theI'` to show that `f x (f' x)` holds and `theI_unique` to show that if `f x y` holds, then `y = f' x`.

For more information about `THE`, `SOME`, etc. see the following:

- [Isabelle/HOL: What does the THE construct denote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750854/isabelle-hol-what-does-the-the-construct-denote)
- [Proving intuitive statements about THE in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411723/proving-intuitive-statements-about-the-in-isabelle)